# $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ in Extended Reals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it true that any sequence $X_n$ converges to $x$ in the extended real number system if and only if $\limsup X_n \le \liminf X_n$?

Comment: Yes; or equivalently, $\limsup X_n=\liminf X_n$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Why is it true?

Comment: Which direction are you not sure about?

Comment: Both, but if you can explain the forward direction, I'll try to work out the other way

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, what you wrote is not quite true. Indeed, consider the constant sequence $x_n=0$ and set $x:=1$. Then $\liminf x_n=0=\limsup x_n$, but $x_n\not\to x$. However, it's clear that you meant to ask:

> If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, then $(x_n)$ converges to an extended real number $x$ iff $\limsup x_n \le \liminf x_n$.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers.
It's easiest to think of $\liminf x_n$ and $\limsup x_n$ as the infimum and supremum, respectively, of all subsequential limits of $(x_n)$.
If this isn't something you've seen before, it's a good exercise to work through. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) may also be helpful.

From this definition, or the others, it should be clear that $\liminf x_n \le \limsup x_n$.

With these two remarks in mind, suppose $(x_n)$ converges to some extended real number $x$.
Then every subsequence of $(x_n)$ must also converge to $x$, so by the above characterization, we have $\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n$.

Conversely suppose $\limsup x_n \le \liminf x_n$. Hence $\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n$. We aim to show that if $x:=\liminf x_n$, then $x_n\to x$. Suppose by contradiction that $x_n\not\to x$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ for which infinitely many terms of the sequence $(x_n)$ lie outside $U$. This gives a subsequence $(y_n)$ of $(x_n)$ such that $y_n\not\in U$ for every $n$. Then any convergent subsequence of $(y_n)$ will not converge to $x$, and thus contradict the assumption $\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n = x$.

It only remains to see that $(y_n)$ has a convergent subsequence. If it is bounded, then this is given to us by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. On the other hand, if it is unbounded, then it has a subsequence which converges to either $\pm\infty$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Why are you able to say "Hence $\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n$"?

Comment: @user23899 It's always true that $\liminf x_n \le \limsup x_n$, so if we additionally assume $\limsup x_n \le \liminf x_n$, then we must have that the two are equal.